# What would be a good paper to cite to explain simulation methods in proc mixed in SAS?

Tags: repeated-measures, sas, multiple-comparisons

In order to analyze data obtained from a repeated measure study, I used the following SAS code:

```
proc mixed;
  class id trial_type trial_seq condition;
  model decision_quality = condition|trial_seq;
  repeated / subject = user_id type=cs;
  lsmeans condition / pdiff CL ADJUST=SIMULATE(SEED=18713 NSAMP=200000);
run;
```

As you can see, I used ADJUST=SIMULATE to find out pair-wise comparison results. What would be a proper citation to explain this method in an academic paper? I think that our reviewers know about a more common correction methods (e.g., Bonferroni and Tukey), but I am not sure if they are aware of the simulation approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect014.htm) says "See Edwards and Berry (1987) for details", so why not use that?

> Edwards, D. and Berry, J. J. (1987), “[The Efficiency of Simulation-Based Multiple Comparisons](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2531545)” *Biometrics*, 43, 913–928.